Is there any site on SE where a question about cultural trends in search engines are allowed?
I have asked this in two places and it has been "off topic" both times.
How did "near me" become a common search qualifier?
How did "near me" become a common search qualifier?
I can't find info on Google, and it should have a factual or fact-based answer. Yet so far it has not been welcomed.
This implies a historical / linguistic angle, in my view:

How did this idea come about? Its first growth in Google Trends was in late 2011, 11+ years after the invention of the search engine and 4+ years after the iPhone.

If it was as simple as "people started searching it as soon as search engines were invented, or as soon as they started carrying smartphones," the answer would be fairly straightforward.
This also strongly implies a cultural component. It's rare for a piece of tech culture to be so thoroughly integrated into the physical world:

I believe I've seen Internet pictures of 2 physical businesses with "Near Me" in the title. I want to say "Dentist Near Me" and some kind of food have been attempted.

Think of how popular "Tweeting", "Googling", "Streaming" have been in our vocabulary - yet there aren't (m)any "Stream City" stores.

Not sure this question has a home in the Stack Exchange network. It may have taken people a while to realize smartphone browsers can access to your location as well; I still use (Google) Maps to search for things near me.


This also strongly implies a cultural component.

This looks too broad to match with one site of the SE network. Not all subjects have a corresponding site, so the answer to the question in the title may be “no”.
But you may start by asking a similar question on Web Applications, focusing the question on one search engine, e.g. by using the [google-search] tag and changing the question to:

When did Google Search added the “near me” filter?

